# importing project into another project Unity

Tags: import, unity-game-engine

I had a working stealth project fully complete quite a while back, but I wanted to import it into another project so I created a unitypackage file for the stealth project. I imported this into another project and I got three errors. One was for the char_Robot.

navmeshagent.velocity assign attempt for 'char_robotGuard_001' is not valid. Input velocity is { NaN, NaN, NaN }. UnityEngine.NavMeshAgent:set_velocity(Vector3) EnemyAnimation:OnAnimatorMove() (at Assets/Scripts/Enemy/EnemyAnimation.cs:51)

That was the first error, the second error was on the PlayerMovement script. The player was not moving and I got an error in the console.

Input Button Attract is not setup. To change the input settings use: Edit -> Project Settings -> Input PlayerMovement.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/Player/PlayerMovement.cs:51)

My final error was that the camera screen was all black. We could faintly the player and the environment.

I am using unity 4.5 and am following the unity stealth tutorial at:

http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/stealth.

Is there any setup that I have to complete or any wrong way I imported the project? Once again I used unity's importing custom package feature to import files. I am using the free version of unity.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you export the package including dependencies? And it seems some of the settings you setup in the other project were not exported along side the package. As the package does not include the projectsettings.asset file. You will have to manually apply those settings again

Answer (score 0):

MX D is right, there are probably asset dependencies that are causing the errors in the new project.

It's hard to say what exactly is causing most of the errors but the input error is because your scripts are in a new project and you haven't defined your input settings.

Go to
Project Settings > Input, and add the "Attract" input button, along with any others that cause errors.

Comment: Adding the Attract input button worked, but I tried exporting the project with all of the dependencies and it gave the same error of NAN but the input button error was gone.

Comment: You're going to have to go to the script with the error and see what's going on at that line.

Comment: I found the problem, it looked like the pausing system was causing this. The line of code, time.timescale = 0, stopped the whole project from working.